# For loop appeneds the last link to all the links

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

So im scraping a newswebsite and every article has it own link, im getting them with a for loop.
the loop gets me all article titles but giv me only one link to all the articles

```
titles = []
dates = []
links = []




containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="col-md-4"]')
for container in containers:
    date = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./div/div/time').text
    title = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./div/h2/a').text
    link = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./div/h2/a').get_attribute("href")
    titles.append(title)
    dates.append(date)
    links.append(link)

my_dict = {'Date': dates,
           'Title':titles,
           'Link':links
          }
df_headline = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```